Two instances of django project (same project) - sharing static?
I'd like to setup two (or more) instances of django project, with separate databases (so far it is easy).
But, I think static files (that are massive - images, css, html ,js etc) - can be only in one place. No need to copy it multiple times, as they are not changing.
Is it possible to setup it that way? Like some hardcoded path to static folder, outside of "project-instance" path?

you ll be hosting those somewhere on a cloud or on server. at that time you ll be using server path instead of local. so that should be fine there.
Apart from that, what you should really use is django-tenants if their are seprate DB
https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
